# Updating XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to update my XML file. But my parsing code is returning null as a result.
This is my code:

```
StreamResourceInfo xml = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("XML/Category.xml", UriKind.Relative));
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml.Stream);

var _result = from x in doc.Elements("Category") where x.Element("Name").Value.Equals("Custom") select x;

_result.First().Element("Subcategories").Value = ",test";
```

And this is my XML file (very simple):

```
   <Categories>
      <Category>
        <Name>Custom</Name>
        <Subcategories></Subcategories>
    </Category>
      <Category>
        <Name>Popular</Name>
        <Subcategories>Most Popular,2nd Popular,3rd Popular</Subcategories>
      </Category>
      ...
   </Categories>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: _result remain always null. Why?

Comment: I don't believe that `_result` is null. I believe it's an empty sequence with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
doc.Elements("Category")
```

That's looking for *root* elements called `Category` (the root element is the only direct child element of the `XDocument`). You want:

```
doc.Root.Elements("Category")
```

or

```
doc.Descendants("Category")
```

Short but complete demonstration:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var result = from x in doc.Root.Elements("Category")
                     where x.Element("Name").Value.Equals("Custom")
                     select x;
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
    }
}
```

With the *exact* XML you've given us, that prints 1.

Comment: It remains always null, with both solutions.
Any ideas?

Comment: @user3415073: It's not clear what you mean by "it" in this case, but the code I've given definitely finds the right "Category" element. See my updated answer for sample code.

Comment: @user3415073: In particular, `_result` most certainly *won't* be null, even in your original code. It'll be an empty sequence, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Now it's works, thanks. I have an other simple question. How to save updated doc?
I tried doc.Save("Category.xml") or Doc.Save(xml.Stream) but doesn't works

Comment: @user3415073: Did you look in the documentation before asking? `XDocument.Save` would be the most obvious first approach... although it depends on whether you have write access to wherever this is actually reading from. (It's not obvious to me what kind of app this is.)

Comment: Read my edited quesiton. I tried doc.Save(xml.Stream) and doc.Save("XML/Category.xml"), but it doesn't works.
I read documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user3415073: Your question hasn't been edited (at the point of me reading) and *shouldn't* be edited to ask about a different problem. Ask a new question if necessary - and with considerably more detail than "it doesn't works".